# Parallel processing mix up

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am new to C# programming.
I am trying to get the number of updates fror a list of servers using background worker. Result for every server is shown in a listview at the report progress method.
I am able to successfully get results using foreach loop, but while trying to get the same results using parallel foreach, all the columns and rows of the listview are mixed up.

for example:
output of foreach loop:
Server Name Status  Updates Available

1. server1  Login to server failed! 0
2. server2  Updates are available   3
3. server3  Updates are available   3
4. server4  Up to Date  0
   and so on..

output of parallel foreach:

1. server1  Updates are available   1
2. server1  Login to server failed! 1
3. server2  Login to server failed! 0
4. server3  Login to server failed! 0
5. server4  Login to server failed! 0
6. server4  Updates are available   3
   and so on..

I have tried locking parts of the code and have also tried using concurrent bag but was not quite able to resolve the issue. Below is the parallelforeach code. I am doing someting wrong? Any suggestions would be of great help.

```
Parallel.ForEach(namelist, /*new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, */line =>
//foreach (string line in namelist)
{
      if (worker.CancellationPending)
      {
             e.Cancel = true;
             worker.ReportProgress(SysCount, obj);
      }
      else
      {
             this.SystemName = line;//file.ReadLine();
             Status.sVariables result = new Status.sVariables();
             result = OneSystem(this.SystemName);
             switch (result.BGWResult)
             {
                    case -1:
                       this.StatusString = "Login to server failed!";
                       break;
                    //other status are assigned here;
             }
             SysCount++;
             bag.Add(this);
      }
      Status returnobj;
      bag.TryTake(out returnobj);
      worker.ReportProgress(SysCount, returnobj);
      Thread.Sleep(200);
});
```

ReportProgress Method:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            Status result = (Status)e.UserState;
            Complete_label.Visible = true;
            if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                listView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add("");
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.SystemName);
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.StatusString);
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.AvailableUpdatesCount.ToString());

                }));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add("");
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.SystemName);
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.StatusString);
                    listView1.Items[result.SysCount - 1].SubItems.Add(result.AvailableUpdatesCount.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {}
                //other stuff
           }
    }
```

Comment: What framework version are you using?

Comment: Output seems legit, since you continue to process after noticing that there is an error( result.BGWResult == -1). Perhapse OneSystem is not threadsafe?

Comment: Why are you mixing up background workers with PLINQ? They are essentially obsolete - use the [Progress<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  class to report progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is that the ListView updating code uses the wrong index to update items. It assumes the `Status.SysCount` property contains the correct index. This may be true if execution happens in sequence, but fails if execution runs in parallel - different threads can finish at different speeds and report progress out-of-order.

The actual problem can be fixed simply by using the ListViewItem object returned by [ListViewItemCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttzhk9y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
    {
        Status result = (Status)e.UserState;
        Complete_label.Visible = true;
        var newItem=listView1.Items.Add("");
        newItem.SubItems.Add(result.SystemName);
        newItem.SubItems.Add(result.StatusString);
        newItem.SubItems.Add(result.AvailableUpdatesCount.ToString());
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

The code has more serious problems though - the `State` class tries to process data in parallel, storing the data in its own properties, then sending itself for reporting. Obviously, the data that gets displayed will always be changing.

A better option is either to create a new State instance inside the loop or, better yet, create a class only for reporting:

```
class StatusProgress 
{
    public string SystemName{get;set;}
    public string StatusString{get;set;}
    public int AvailableUpdatesCount {get;set;}
}

....
int sysCount=0;
Parallel.ForEach(namelist, line =>
{
    var progress=new StatusProgress();
    progress.SystemName = line;//file.ReadLine();

    Status.sVariables result = new Status.sVariables();
    result = OneSystem(line);
    switch (result.BGWResult)
    {
        case -1:
            progress.StatusString = "Login to server failed!";
            break;
                //other status are assigned here;
    }
    var count=Interlocked.Increment(ref sysCount);
  }
  worker.ReportProgress(count, progress);
});
```

Notice that instead of `SysCount++` is use `Interlocked.Increment` to increase the value atomically *and* get a copy of the incremented value. If I didn't do that, multiple threads could modify `SysCount` before I had a chance to report progress.

The progress reporting code would change to use `StateProgress`

```
        StatusProgress result = (StatusProgress)e.UserState;
```

Finally, the BackgroundWorker is obsolete as the Task Parallel Library offers everything the BGW did and more, in a far more lightweight manner. For example, you can [cancel the parallel loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx) by using a CancellationToken and report progress in a type-safe manner using the [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Most asynchronous methods in .NET recognize CancellationToken and Progress which means you can report progress and cancel asynchronous tasks easily as [shown here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx).

The code could be rewritten like this:

On a UI form:

```
private void ReportServerProgress(StatusProgress result)
{
    Complete_label.Visible = true;
    var newItem=listView1.Items.Add("");
    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.SystemName);
    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.StatusString);
    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.AvailableUpdatesCount.ToString());
    //other stuff
}   

CancellationTokenSource _cts;
Progress<StatusProgress> _progress;

public void StartProcessiong()
{
    _cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
   _progress=new Progress<StatusProgress(progress=>ReportServerProgress(progress);
   StartProcessing(/*input*/,_cts.Token,_progress);
}

public void CancelLoop()
{
   if (_cts!=null)
      _cts.Cancel();
}
```

The processing code can be on the same form or any other class. In fact, it's better to separate the UI from the processing code, especially when you have non-trivial processing, eg calling each server to determine its status

```
public void StartProcessing(/*input parameters*/,
                    CancellationTokenSource token,
                    IProgress<StatusProgress> progress)
{
    .....
    var po=new ParallelOptions();
    po.CancellationToken=token;
    Parallel.ForEach(namelist, po,line =>
    {
       var status=new StatusProgress();
       status.SystemName = line;//file.ReadLine();
       Status.sVariables result = new Status.sVariables();
       result = OneSystem(line);
       switch (result.BGWResult)
       {
           case -1:
               progress.StatusString = "Login to server failed!";
               break;
               //other status are assigned here;
       }
       progress.Report(status);
    }
}
```

Many asynchronous .NET methods accept a cancellation token, so you can pass it eg to a Web Service call and ensure both the loop and any outstanding long calls are cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are all mixed up because you are using a parallel operation to write to global state, eg `SystemName` and `StatusString`, thus the contents of those global variables will end up all mixed up when you try to read and print their values.

You could introduce a `lock`, but this would completely defeat the point of the `Parallel.ForEach`. So either abandon he use of the `Parallel.ForEach` (which seems to serve no useful purpose in this instance) or you need to gather data and ensure it's sent to the reporter in a thread-safe fashion.

To further explain, let's examine the code:

```
this.SystemName = line; // <- the worker has now written to this, which is global to all workers
...
result = OneSystem(this.SystemName); // <- another worker may have overwritten SystemName at this point
...
                   this.StatusString = "Login to server failed!"; // <- again writing to shared variable
         ...
         bag.Add(this); // <- now trying to "thread protect" already corrupted data
```

So if you must run the loop in parallel, each worker must update only its own isolated data then push that off to the GUI marshalling report method.

Comment: The lock won't help - the UI is updated in a backgroundworker's ProcessChanged event which always runs on the UI thread. Thread safety is not the issue here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, um no, clearly thread safety is an issue, as evidenced by the output.

Comment: Not in the way you think - the *thread-safe* code in `ProgressChanged` updates the wrong ListView item because it assumes the state object contains the index of the newly added ListViewItem. The state is passed in a "safe" manner as the payload of the event - but the instance is then reused. The code has many serious issues that can't be solved with locking

Comment: I am using parallel foreach as i have hundreds of servers in the list.. just to improve the performance.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos would you please explain "state is passed in a "safe" manner as the payload of the event - _but the instance is then reused. The code has many serious issues_ "

Comment: @Aditi check my answer. While you do use the `ReportProgress` event, you end up updating the wrong ListViewItem. You also keep using the same `Status` object even though you modify its properties in each iteration.

Comment: @Aditi, I have updated my answer to try and better explain where things are going wrong.

Comment: I understand now @DavidArno. Thank you very much for your help. This was my first post on this platform and I got more than what i had expected..I have posted another question about a problem related to the same program. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475298/n-clicks-on-a-button-gives-n-outputs-required-is-only-one-output-resulting-from) Any help will be much appreciated.