# n clicks on a button gives n outputs. Required is only one output resulting from one click

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

ok.. so i have no idea why this is happening.I saw a similar problem in Java i guess.. but i don't understand any of that stuff. I am working with C# where I have a `listview` which is updated with remote servers update status on clicking of a button. i have got the code working for this. but when i click on the same button again, the output is displayed twice. If i click on it one more time the output is displayed thrice and so on!!
for example:
on first click:

```
xxx     login to server failed
yyy     login to server failed
```

on second click:

```
xxx     login to server failed
xxx     login to server failed
yyy     login to server failed
yyy     login to server failed
```

I am using a `backgroundworker`, and a parallel `foreach` loop in it.I have put in all the involved functions here so that there's all the information there.. sorry if that's too much!
Here's my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                        //get update button
    {
        GlobalVariables._count = 0;
        Status.statusProgress obj1 = new Status.statusProgress();
        if (getupdate_button.Text == "Stop")
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            getupdate_button.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            getupdate_button.Text = "Stop";
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            //do stuff
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        }
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please wait till the pervious operation is completed!");
            }
            else 
            {
                Complete_label.Text = "Cancelling...";
                Complete_label.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(obj1);                                //calling background worker
        }
    }
```

DO WORK:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)                         //the boss-- the background worker
    {
        System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker;
        worker = (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)sender;
        Status obj1 = new Status();
        Status.statusProgress obj = new Status.statusProgress();

        if ((backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            obj1.Calculation(worker, e);
        }
        e.Result = obj;
    }
```

CALCULATION METHOD:

```
    public void Calculation(System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Status.statusProgress obj = (Status.statusProgress)e.Argument;
        //stuff

            var file = File.ReadAllLines(obj.SourceFile);

            List<string> namelist = null;
            namelist = new List<string>(file);
            Parallel.ForEach(namelist, /*new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, */line =>
            //foreach (string line in namelist)
            {
                var progress = new statusProgress();
                progress.TotalSysCount = obj.TotalSysCount;
                Status.statusProgress result = new Status.statusProgress();
                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    worker.ReportProgress(result.SysCount, result);
                }
                else
                {
                    //this.SystemName = line;//file.ReadLine();                        
                    progress.SystemName = line;
                    //result = progress;
                    result = OneSystem(line);
                    //work with result
        }
                count1 = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
                //stuff
                worker.ReportProgress(count1, progress);
                Thread.Sleep(200);

             });

        }
    }
```

REPORT PROGRESS METHOD:

```
     private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    try
                {
                    var newItem = listView1.Items.Add("");
                    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.SystemName);
                    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.StatusString);
                    newItem.SubItems.Add(result.AvailableUpdatesCount.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {}

            update_text(result);
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            int perc = (int)((result.SysCount * 100) / result.TotalSysCount);
            progressBar1.Value = perc;
            Complete_label.Text = perc.ToString()+"%";
            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
                Complete_label.Text = "Complete!";
                getupdate_button.Enabled = false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: wow, i am so tired from writing "give us some code!" over and over again... _"sorry if thats too much! Here's my code:"_ is sooo refreshing :)

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize `backgroundWorker1`, I suspect you might have duplicated subscribing to an event. `backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;`

Comment: @Hari Prasad i dont know what you mean by initialize backgroundworker1 code.. i just added it using the toolbox of visual studio...i have the definition though :private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;

Comment: @Aditi you must have in your code something like `var backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();`

Comment: Consider using a Completed event instead of `if (progressBar1.Value == 100)`. For properly handling Errors and cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the issue is here:

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
```

If whenever you do the whole *click* you add a `ProgressChanged` event handler, after each click you'll be increasing the number of times that the event is being handled.

At the end of the day, you should add event handlers in some application's initialization code or in your class constructor instead of doing so in the click event handler. That is, you'll be sure that you're adding `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event handler once per application life-cycle.

Comment: And/Or just create a new Backgroundworker each time. They're cheap and it absolves you from keeping track of all that state.

Comment: I think you've nailed it. I always work on the premise that if my code does a `+=` to add a handler that I also make sure that I do a `-=` to remove it when it isn't needed.

Comment: @Enigmativity Maybe removing the event handler might be a solution, but take care about making this thread-safe, because what happens if many threads add handlers and remove handlers...? :D

Comment: I initially thought so to.. but even commenting out that particular line gives the same issue.

Comment: I also tried a -= after callinng the background worker... but it didnt work either.

Comment: @Henk Holterman teh background worker used here is defined in the windows form disigned generated code. which is why it is accesed from muliple methods. how can i declare a new background worker everytime?

Comment: In the button_click, after you've checked and Canceled the previous one, `backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();` and the set _all_ properties and eventhandlers in code.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer i tried adding that statement to the following methods.. but in this case the first output itself was given two times.                                                                                                                 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @Aditi And the subsequent ones? Does output the thing more times?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Holterman i have put  backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(obj1);  It seems the DoWork is never reached when i do this.  It might sound silly.. but what dis you mean when you said " set all properties and eventhandlers in code"

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer yes it keeps increasing.

Comment: Your posted code sets the `ProgressChanged += ...`,  you now have to do that for the DoWork and Completed events too. And the Suports... properties.

Comment: @Aditi Now with your code I can't see where's the next issue, but you know it will be in the same way of `ProgressChanged`. Investigate that further in your source code as @HenkHolterman has commented out here...